# How do I authenticate POST request from external website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a Rails website that takes POSTed data and saves it into a database in a controller action called "create".  In my controller, I have specified

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

because the Rails website will be receiving this POSTed data from an external app (a Raspberry Pi sending POSTed data through python).

This setup works well, however I realize I have opened myself to anyone being able to save data to my database if they know the Rails url and parameters, not just my Raspberry Pi.

**Is there anyway I can authenticate the POST request so my Rails app only saves data coming from my Raspberry Pi?**

The only thing I can think of is adding a "secret" value that's passed from the Raspberry Pi and is checked for in my Rails controller before any data is saved to the database.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret would be a suitable solution for that. You have multiple options to implement the secret:

- An additional parameter to your call.
- HTTP Basic-Auth header.
- Two-way SSL.

The first 2 are only secure if communication is done via HTTPS or over a private secure network.

Depending on the situation you might also consider some other options, like listening only on localhost and opening ssh tunnel between the 2 servers to make a call.